# How to use "really simple captcha" with Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, captcha

I am a newbie and I tried the following code in functions.php under the theme folder, but it didn't work. Can someone tell me how to solve this? Thanks.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_lost_password_form' , 'mytheme_captcha' );

function mytheme_captcha() {

$captcha_instance = new ReallySimpleCaptcha();
$captcha_instance->bg = array( 0, 0, 0 );
$word = $captcha_instance->generate_random_word();
$prefix = mt_rand();
$captcha_instance->generate_image( $prefix, $word );
$correct = $captcha_instance->check( $prefix, $the_answer_from_respondent );
$captcha_instance->remove( $prefix );
}
```